# If Unity launcher is auto-hide, how will elements on upper panel behave?

Tags: unity, launcher

When launcher hides to left, active windows will maximize their borders to full screen. Alignment between windows left border and windows buttons + global menu on upper panel would be lost, it will look very strange. I want to know what is the real plan on auto-hiding.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: you could bring this up as a bug report on launchpad.

Comment: Even better: add to the whiteboard of [this blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-specialized-unity-form-factor).

Comment: I'd agree, please open a bug for this as it's an issue not covered as yet. You can open it against unity in launchpad.net.

Answer (score 8):

It's true that the maximised window will then have window buttons which are a little inside from the left edge of the window. We haven't tested this yet, our position for the moment is that keeping them in the same place on the screen is more important than keeping them against the left edge of the window. We'll have to update that understanding once we're in a position to test it.

In answer to your question: that is the real plan on auto-hiding :-) but it may not be the final answer.